# How do i get the context to test my view page?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm trying to test my search results to check the response when there are no results.

this is the function in my view:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         result = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         query = self.request.GET.get('q')
         result['book'] = get_object_or_404(books,ISBN = query)
         return result
```

this is my test class and function

```
class Test_Search_results_view(TestCase):
    def test_no_results(self):
        response1 = self.client.get('/TextSearch/results1/?books=new&q=9780815345244')
        response2 = self.client.get('/TextSearch/results2/?books=new&author=Bruce+Alberts&Book+Name=Molecular+Biology+of+the+Cell&edition=6')
        self.assertEqual(response1.status_code, 404)
        self.assertEqual(response2.status_code, 404)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response2.context['book'],[])
```

but i keep getting this error

```
self.assertQuerysetEqual(response2.context['book'],[])
  File "C:----\context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'book'
```

how do I check if my book query got empty results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this line: `result['book'] = get_object_or_404(books,ISBN = query)` causes `404` to be raised, then, you will have nothing in `result['book']`. Because the `404` is and exception which is raised. `get_object_or_404` does not return an empty value which you could assert in your test.